# Fetch Ticket message body using 'TestSimple' invoker of 'ArticleCreate' trigger

Tags: perl, otrs

I'm using invoker TestSimple.pm of trigger 'ArticleCreate'. (Ideally should've created a new invoker!) I'm able to receive the json data of the ticket correctly via REST web service.
I want an additional ticket attribute with this-> 'ticket body'. How can i modify the invoker (perl file) so that it also sends ticket body in the json data? Or is their any other trigger that can give me this out-of-the-box?
I went through OTRS manual and getting confused again-n-again :(
So, if someone can give me proper link that will also do!

System details:
1. OTRS v4.0
2. Apache web server

[Edit] Added the TestSimple.pm file.
This is the [link](http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?t=27465) I referred.

```
    #copyright (C) 2001-2014 OTRS AG, http://otrs.com/
# --
# This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. For details, see
# the enclosed file COPYING for license information (AGPL). If you
# did not receive this file, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.txt.
# --

package Kernel::GenericInterface::Invoker::Test::TestSimple;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Kernel::System::VariableCheck qw(IsString IsStringWithData);
use Kernel::System::Ticket;

our $ObjectManagerDisabled = 1;

=head1 NAME

Kernel::GenericInterface::Invoker::Test::Test - GenericInterface test Invoker backend

=head1 SYNOPSIS

=head1 PUBLIC INTERFACE

=over 4

=cut

=item new()

usually, you want to create an instance of this
by using Kernel::GenericInterface::Invoker->new();

=cut

sub new {
my ( $Type, %Param ) = @_;

# allocate new hash for object
my $Self = {};
bless( $Self, $Type );

# check needed params
if ( !$Param{DebuggerObject} ) {
return {
Success => 0,
ErrorMessage => "Got no DebuggerObject!"
};
}

$Self->{DebuggerObject} = $Param{DebuggerObject};
$Self->{TicketObject} = Kernel::System::Ticket->new(%Param);

return $Self;
}

=item PrepareRequest()

prepare the invocation of the configured remote webservice.
This will just return the data that was passed to the function.

my $Result = $InvokerObject->PrepareRequest(
Data => { # data payload
...
},
);

my %Article = $TicketObject->ArticleGet(
ArticleID => $Param{Data}->{ArticleID},
UserID => $Param{Data}->{CustomerID},
);

$Result = {
Success => 1, # 0 or 1
ErrorMessage => '', # in case of error
Data => { # data payload after Invoker
...
},
};

=cut

sub PrepareRequest {
my ( $Self, %Param ) = @_;
my %TicketInfo = $Self->{TicketObject}->ArticleGet(
ArticleID => $Param{Data}->{ArticleID},
userID => $Param{Data}->{CustomerID},
);

return {
Success => 1,
Data => $TicketInfo{Body},
};
}

=item HandleResponse()

handle response data of the configured remote webservice.
This will just return the data that was passed to the function.

my $Result = $InvokerObject->HandleResponse(
#my $Result = $TicketBodyObject->HandleResponse(
ResponseSuccess => 1, # success status of the remote webservice
ResponseErrorMessage => '', # in case of webservice error
Data => { # data payload
...
},
);

$Result = {
Success => 1, # 0 or 1
ErrorMessage => '', # in case of error
Data => { # data payload after Invoker
%Article
},
};

=cut

sub HandleResponse {
my ( $Self, %Param ) = @_;

# if there was an error in the response, forward it
if ( !$Param{ResponseSuccess} ) {
return {
Success => 0,
ErrorMessage => $Param{ResponseErrorMessage},
};
}

return {
Success => 1,
Data => $Param{Data},
};
}

1;

=back

=head1 TERMS AND CONDITIONS

This software is part of the OTRS project (L<http://otrs.org/>).

This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. For details, see
the enclosed file COPYING for license information (AGPL). If you
did not receive this file, see L<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.txt>.

=cut
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code of TestSimple.pm, or links to the documentation you are referring to.

Comment: @simbabque any idea or comments?

Answer (score 1):

PrepareRequest only knows about the `TicketID` and `ArticleID` it is operating on.
You'll need to look up the data you need to pass in the `PrepareRequest()` sub of your Invoker, and then return it in the Data parameter.

Check the code below for an example how to add the article body:

```
sub PrepareRequest {
    my ( $Self, %Param ) = @_;

    my %Article = $Kernel::OM->Get('Kernel::System::Ticket')->ArticleGet(
        ArticleID => $Param{Data}{ArticleID},
        UserID => 1,
    );

    return {
        Success => 1,
        Data => {
            TicketID  => $Param{Data}{TicketID},
            ArticleID => $Param{Data}{ArticleID},
            Body      => $Article{Body},
        },
    };
}
```